# Displaying object property in another class

Tags: objective-c, object, detailview

I am trying to display the a few properties of an object class that I have created in a another class (in DetailView.m) but I am struggling to figure out exactly how to do so. I've tried looking it up but have yet to come up with a solution (I am very new to objective-c and iOS dev). I started with a basic Master-view application.

I successfully have a tableview which displays 4 different players but now what I want is that when a user clicks on a specific player they will move into the DetailView from which they will be able to click from three buttons and have a label which will display the addition player information.

Player.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Player : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *position;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger age;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *club;

-(NSString *) playerDetail;


@end
```

I fill out some random values in AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "Player.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    Player *player1 = [[Player alloc]init];
    player1.name = @"Cristiano Ronaldo";
    player1.age = 27;
    player1.position = @"Winger";
    player1.club = @"Real Madrid";

    Player *player2 = [[Player alloc]init];
    player2.name = @"Neymar";
    player2.age = 21;
    player2.position = @"Striker";
    player2.club = @"Barcelona";

    Player *player3 = [[Player alloc]init];
    player3.name = @"Juan Mata";
    player3.age = 25;
    player3.position = @"Midfielder";
    player3.club = @"Manchester United";

    Player *player4 = [[Player alloc]init];
    player4.name = @"Thiago Silva";
    player4.age = 27;
    player4.position = @"Center Back";
    player4.club = @"PSC";

    NSMutableArray *players = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:player1, player2, player3, player4, nil];

    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;
    MasterViewController *masterController = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    masterController.players = players;



    return YES;
}

 //Rest of code is the generic boilerplate provided by Xcode

@end
```

And I am trying to display the player's position, age, club name when either of the respective buttons are clicked. I try handling this in DetailViewController.m.

DetailViewController.m:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "Player.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (IBAction)positionInfoButton {
//Stuck here
}

- (IBAction)ageInfoButton {

//Stuck here
}

- (IBAction)clubInfoButton {

//Stuck here
}
```

I am stuck in the action methods for postionInfoButton etc, and I am trying to display the players position when the user clicks a button in the detailView. In DetailView.h i declared:

```
IBOutlet UILabel *infoLabel;
```

I try doing the following in positionInfoButton() to try and change the label:

```
infoLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Plays in the position of @%", self.position]
```

but this does not work. I do not think I can call self here but I do not know why. Is there another way of getting that player property for that specific player?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your setup correctly, you should have access to the `detailItem` property, like this:

```
- (IBAction)positionInfoButton {
    infoLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Plays in the position of %@", [self.detailItem position];
}
```

Note that in your format string you used `@%` as the placeholder - this is wrong, swap the characters to get the correct placeholder: `%@`.

Comment: When i do this I get two flags. 1 is a warning: "Format specifies type 'id' but the argument has type 'CGPoint'" .... and I also get an error "Multiple methods named 'position' found with mismatched result,paramter,or type attribues" I do not know how to deal with the warning. And I am pretty sure I do not have postions named twice so I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use prepare for segue, something like this,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Assume self.view is the table view
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    DetailObject *detail = [self detailForIndexPath:path];
    [segue.destinationViewController setDetail:detail];
}
```

right before you do segue.destinationViewController, do something like this

```
[detail setPosition: players[indexPathForSelectedRow]objectForKey@"position"];
```

Something along thoses lines, ,make sure in your details.h file you have a variable NSString *position

Answer (score 0):

the solution was actually as follows:

In DetailViewController.H I had to add the following property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Player *detailPlayer;
```

postionInfoButton Method do this:

```
- (IBAction)positionInfoButton {

    infoLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.detailPlayer position]];
    NSLog(@"Pressed Position button %@", [self.detailPlayer position]);

}
```

And then finally, within MasterViewController.m change the prepareForSegue() method as follows:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    Player *play = _players[indexPath.row];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailPlayer:play];
}
```

Here I made the change to Create an instance of type Player, and then call on the segue to use that player information for the following view.

Thank you for the suggestions above.